# Sort array by strings nested in dictionaries in the array

Tags: arrays, sorting, dictionary, nsstring, plist

so I have a rather complicated plist system. Here is a image showing the data structure.

[image]

Is is possible to sort the whole 'Staff' array by the strings with the key 'name' that are nested inside these dictionaries? The strings will of course have values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get that staff `NSArray` first, And sort it using `NSSortDescriptor` like usual
Here's my code

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Contacts" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *contacts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *staff = [contacts objectForKey:@"Staff"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", [staff sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for answering! Figured it out a while ago, but still thankful for you to answer me! /Jacob